# How to add a modal view onto current view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have this code:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
JUnlockController *passcodeView = [[JUnlockController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeView animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is, when i have a modal view controller open in my app, it doesn't appear on top of it. I want to be able to find out which is the current viewcontroller that the user is looking at, so I can display it on top of there.

Comment: Taken from your code, as far as I can see, you present a "vanilla", meaning an empty view controller. How do you define the views within that view controller? In the init method or in the loadView method? Or in Interface Builder?

Comment: What is displayed instead of the view that you want to display?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:passcodeView animated:YES];
```

use:

```
[self presentModalViewController:passcodeView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

If your app is only navigated by that nav controller, you can ask it which viewController is visible:

```
[self.navigationController.visibleViewController presentModalViewController:passcodeView animated:YES];
```

Or else you can leverage the [UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification) by having all ov your view controllers extend a custom class which registers for this on `viewWillAppear` and unregisters in `viewWillDissapear`; and in your custom base class you implement the callback which displays your modal.

**edit** note that this assumes you have a `self.navigationController` in your app delegate (which you setup). You may need to use something like `self.window.rootViewController` instead.